# Traefik router giving 403 error when working with Kestrel

Tags: asp.net-core, traefik, kestrel-http-server

I have a problem running a small .NET Core web app with Kestrel and trying to use Traefik for reverse proxying.

I have the app running at https://127.0.0.1:44321 and have opened port 80 and 443 in the router, I run the traefik.exe on a Win7 machine.

This is my toml-file:

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]
debug = true
logLevel = "DEBUG"

[web]
address = ":8085"

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]

[backends]

  [backends.backend1]

    [backends.backend1.servers]
      [backends.backend1.servers.server0]
        url = "https://127.0.0.1:44321"
        weight = 1

[frontends]

  [frontends.frontend1]
    entryPoints = ["http"]
    backend = "backend1"
    passHostHeader = true
    [frontends.frontend1.routes]
      [frontends.frontend1.routes.route0]
        rule = "mysite.ddns.net"
    
[acme]
email = "mymail@gmail.com"
storage = "acme.json"
caServer = "https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
entryPoint = "https"
  [acme.httpChallenge]
  entryPoint = "http"

[[acme.domains]]
  main = "mysite.ddns.net"
```

No errors just

```
INFO[2018-08-22T11:49:13+02:00] Server configuration reloaded on :80
INFO[2018-08-22T11:49:13+02:00] Server configuration reloaded on :443
INFO[2018-08-22T11:49:13+02:00] Server configuration reloaded on :8085
```